# Get Each Value on an XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<HiddenTopicsValues TopicCodes="TopicValues">
  <Topic>
    <Code>topic_aboutme</Code>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Topic>
  <Topic>
    <Code>topic_aboutyou</Code>
    <Value>1</Value>
</HiddenTopicsValues>
```

My goal is to create a Dictionary that lets the `<Code>` act as the Key, and `<Value>` as the Value (of the Dictionary). I declared the dictionary as shown below:

```
Dictionary<string,int> dictionary_topics = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

And used a for loop to iterate all the values in the XML:

```
    // Load XML Document
    XmlDocument xmlTopics = new XmlDocument();
    xmlTopics.Load(path);

    // Get All Hidden Topics
    XmlNodeList ndTopics = xmlTopics.GetElementsByTagName("Topic");

    for (int i = 0; i < ndTopics.Count; i++)
    {

        string _topicCode = ndTopics[i].InnerText[0].ToString();
        int _topicValue = ndTopics[i].InnerText[1].ToString();

        // Add Topic to Dictionary
        dictionary_topics.Add(_topicCode, _topicValue);
    }
```

I thought that this: `ndTopics[i].InnerText[0]` would return this: `topic_aboutme`
And this: `ndTopics[0].InnerText[1]` would return this: `1`
Based on the given XML.

I tried displaying `ndTopics[0].InnerText` and it shows this:

```
topic_aboutme1
```

How can I separate the `topic_aboutme(<Code>)` and `1(<Value>)`?

Forgive my naiveness, I'm not really used in utilising XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real easy in Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Topic")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Code"), y => (string)y.Element("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually works!
What is the difference between `XMLDocument` and `XDocument`? And is there anyway to simplify the syntax used in the answer?

Comment: XDocument is the Net enhanced Xml library that uses Linq.  I like the syntax in my answer.  It is concise but still easy to understand.  The one thing I do not like about the XmlDocument class is you cannot do a lot of things in one instruction.  I believe in grouping code by adding white spaces to make code easy to read and understand.So there is always a trade-off of using too little and too many instructions.There is a terminology from the 1960s called Power Programming.  Since memory was expensive, it cost less to have less programming instructions, but it made code harder to understand.